Unmatched route on react-native

I have a project structured like the picture. I want to go from GetStarted.js to Instruction.js. I'm using the following code:
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} 
                        onPress={() => router.push('./Instructions.js')}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            Welcome
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

But I get an unmatched Route error. I've tried with different folders, and it works.
I don't understand which one is the correct code to switch to a file.js in the same folder. (In this case, 'components'.)
I'm pretty sure it's a simple solution, but I can't find it.

Create the pages in the app directory. Something like this:
app
  index.tsx
  instructions.tsx

Navigate from index:
router.replace('/instructions');

See Create pages with Expo Router for details.

I just discovered that I had to create the new folders under 'app', not randomly.
Now is working.
Thanks!

You are posting no need answer.
